# DigitalOcean: Django, Channels, Redis & Daphne

Tags: django, redis, digital-ocean, django-channels, daphne

I am having issues with running websockets on DigitalOcean's App platform.  I think I am fundamentally missing a configuration as it relates to Daphne.

Here is my setup:

Daphne 4.0.0
Channels-Redis 3.4.1

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

...

    # Third-party
    'channels',

...

WSGI_APPLICATION = "config.wsgi.application"
ASGI_APPLICATION = "config.asgi.application"

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://blah.com',
    'https://*.blah.com',
]

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

ASGI.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.dev')

import django
django.setup()



from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
asgi_app = get_asgi_application()


import api_waitlist.routing
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter, get_default_application
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack



application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': asgi_app,
    'websocket': 
        AllowedHostsOriginValidator(AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            api_waitlist.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        
        ))
    ),  # new
})
```

DigitalOcean Configurations

DigitalOcean App:
"run command" located under App>Settings>Run Command:

```
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8080 config.asgi:application
```

Redis Configuration:
Redis is set up using DigitalOcean's managed Redis database. The connection string is provided by DigitalOcean. The app level variable "REDIS_URL" that contains the connection string is:

```
rediss://default:password_here@fs-dev-redis-do-user-xxxx-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com:25061
```

React Frontend (React is within the Django project scaffolding):
The React frontend code to establish the websocket connection is:

```
wb = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/waitlist/");
```

The frontend browser console error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue specifically for the DigitalOcean app platform:

- The websocket URL must be using "wss" when the site is using https
- The domain is required instead of referencing the localhost
- The port number is not required in the URL

This is what the final URL looks like:

wss://your_domain.com/ws/waitlist/